# My two queries work separately but when I nest one inside of the other it no longer works

Tags: mysql, subquery

My first query is:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN (Transactions.RegFunction = '1' AND Transactions.RegYear = "2017") THEN RegAmt END) AS GroupCurrsumFee, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (Transactions.RegFunction = '1' AND Transactions.RegYear = "2017") THEN Transactions.LMSCAmt END) AS IndCurrsumFee
FROM AllTransactions
```

My second query is:

```
SELECT GroupAmt 
FROM GroupFees
WHERE
'2016-11-01' BETWEEN BeginDate AND EndDate
AND RegYear = "2016"
AND GROUPID = "14"
AND RegFunction = 1;
```

When I run that query it returns the below:

```
|  GroupAmt  |
|   5.00     |
```

When I nest the second query inside of the first so that it can return that data in a column alias it does not show up. I have the two queries combined and written as the below:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN (Transactions.RegFunction = '1' AND Transactions.RegYear = "2017") THEN RegAmt END) AS GroupCurrsumFee, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Transactions.RegFunction = '1' AND Transactions.RegYear = "2017") THEN Transactions.LMSCAmt END) AS IndCurrsumFee,
(SELECT GroupAmt FROM GroupFees
    WHERE
    '2016-11-01' BETWEEN BeginDate AND EndDate
    AND RegYear = "2016"
    AND GROUPID = "14"
    AND RegFunction = 1) AS GroupFee
FROM AllTransactions
```

Comment: Please edit your question and at least show us the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join instead. Given the possibility that query might return NULL I suggest a left join with join condition that is always true. (Yes a bit "hacky".) Note, there is no guarantee that subquery returns just one row. If it does your overall result may not be what you are expecting.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
        WHEN (
                Transactions.RegFunction = '1'
                AND Transactions.RegYear = "2017"
                )
            THEN RegAmt
        END) AS GroupCurrsumFee
, SUM(CASE 
        WHEN (
                Transactions.RegFunction = '1'
                AND Transactions.RegYear = "2017"
                )
            THEN Transactions.LMSCAmt
        END) AS IndCurrsumFee
   , GroupFee.GroupAmt
FROM AllTransactions
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GroupAmt
    FROM GroupFees
    WHERE '2016-11-01' BETWEEN BeginDate
            AND EndDate
        AND RegYear = '2016'
        AND GROUPID = '14'
        AND RegFunction = 1
    ) AS GroupFee on 1=1
```